# Count No Of 1's Colony From [1,0] 2D Array Using C#

Tags: c#, arrays, image-processing, recursion

I have a 2D array of integers which stores only values [1,0] as shown below.

```
int[,] INPUT = new int[10, 10] {
    {1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0},
    {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0},
    {0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1},
    {1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},
    {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0},
    {0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0},
    {1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0},
    {0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1},
    {0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},
};
```

[image: Colony Count In This Array Are "3".]

I need to identify a Colony count for the input image, where a Colony is defined as a contiguous sequence of 1s (Like in this array, there are 3 colony of 1's).  Connection between 1s can be either adjacent or on the diagonal.

I am required to use recursion for this.

```
class Program
    {
    public static int count;
    public static int colony;
    public static int[,] INPUT;
    public static int rows = 10;
    public static int cols = 10;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] INPUT = new int[10, 10] {
                       {1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0},
                       {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0},
                       {0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1},
                       {1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},
                       {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0},
                       {0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0},
                       {1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0},
                       {0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1},
                       {0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0},
                       {0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},
        };

        // Showing All Values From Upper 2D array
        Console.WriteLine("Input File Contain: \n");
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(INPUT[i, j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        // Getting Total 1's Count Only
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                if (INPUT[i, j] == 1)
                {
                    count = count + 1;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        // Getting Total 1's Colony Only            
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                if (INPUT[i, j] == 1)
                {
                    INPUT[i, j] = 0;
                    colony = GetColony(i, j);
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Counts Of 1 Are: " + count);
        Console.WriteLine("Counts Of 1's Colony Are: " + colony );
    }

    static public int GetColony(int i, int j)
    {
        if ((i < rows) && (j < cols))
        {        
            if ((INPUT[i - 1, j] == 1) || (INPUT[i + 1, j] == 1) || (INPUT[i, j - 1] == 1) || (INPUT[i, j + 1] == 1))
            {
                INPUT[i, j] = 0;
                return GetColony(i, j);
            }
            else
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is one of Connected Component Analysis, see this explanation at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/336915/Connected-Component-Labeling-Algorithm

Comment: @Jiby, Thanks for a helpful link...